# SQL JOIN where tab1.colA value is in tab2.colB's JSON list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a few tables: `products`, `transactions`, `styles`. SQL query joins `products` and `styles` into one table that contains all information that I technically need. However I need to sort that information by `timestamp` of when that `product` was purchased. For that reason I need to join `transactions` with the output of previous join:

transactions

```
| id | timestamp           | productIDs     |
|----|---------------------|----------------|
| 0  | 2014-08-04 07:56:54 | ["ID1", "ID2"] |
| 1  | 2014-08-04 07:56:57 | ["ID3", "ID4"] |
```

products + styles joined

```
| productID | styleID | ... |
|-----------|---------|-----|
| ID1       | aaa     | ... |
| ID2       | bbb     | ... |
| ID3       | ccc     | ... |
| ID4       | ddd     | ... |
```

What I'm looking for:

```
| productID | styleID | timestamp           | ... |
|-----------|---------|---------------------|-----|
| ID1       | aaa     | 2014-08-04 07:56:54 | ... |
| ID2       | bbb     | 2014-08-04 07:56:54 | ... |
| ID3       | ccc     | 2014-08-04 07:56:57 | ... |
| ID4       | ddd     | 2014-08-04 07:56:57 | ... |
```

For each row from `products + styles`, a timestamp is added from `transactions`, where `productID` is present in `productIDs` JSON structure.

How do I perform such join?

Comment: Can a productID show up in multiple transactions? What should the outcome be in that case?

Comment: Which version of MySql are you using?

Comment: Your transaction table in not normalized. Ideally it should have multiple rows for each unique entry.

Comment: @Error_2646 it can. In that case it should get the 'oldest' timestamp.

Comment: @Rohit.007 5.7.19

Comment: I think I will end up creating a table that contains just transaction items and links back to transactions by transactionID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Rohit.007 Your transaction table in not normalized. Ideally it should have multiple rows for each unique entry.

I ended up creating a separate table that holds a numeric index, transaction ID and product ID.
It holds separate rows for each product bought as part of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this to your where clause

```
AND exists(select value from openjson(productids) p where p.value in (select productid from products))
```

Comment: The openjson() functions is not available in the previous versions of MySql.